# Django Extend Default User Model

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am searching for a way to easily add more character fields to the default user model from Django. This question has been asked, but I couldn't find an up to date answer.

I let Django handle all the authenticating and logging in, so I don't want to create a custom user model, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
      pass # add fields here
```

in **`settings.py`** add:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app_name.CustomUser"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just inherit from AbstractUser.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    custom_fields....
```

You can then set this as your AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "<my-app>.User"
```

Django should still be able to handle all the authentication, etc.